# Android studio not launching with custom VM options

Tags: android-studio

I'm using android studio v3.6.3. My laptop has 16GB RAM with i7 (7th Gen processor). I tried configuring the custom VM options in the Android studio. Following is my configuration

```
# custom Android Studio VM options, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html
-Xmx8g
-XX:MaxPermSize=1g
-Xms1g
```

After saving this config, Android studio is not opening for me. If I set -Xms to 512m, it is launching. For any value greater than 512m for Xms, the Android studio is not opening. I need to set the value as 1g to avoid Out of memory error. Any inputs to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
The issue was with the value of the system environment variable for _JAVA_OPTIONS. In the environment variable the max heap was specified as -Xmx512m, but in the custom VM options I tried to set the initial heap size(-Xms as 1g). Since the max heap was less than the initial heap space, android studio was not launching. I modified the value of -Xmx to 8g in the environment variable and the issue was resolved